# "Charts" Not working in Xcode 8

Tags: charts, swift3, xcode8

I am using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

I installed by `"pod Charts"`

Once i updated to Xcode 8 , it showed  -

> “Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be
>   configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit >
>   Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or
>   use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

I changed the "**Use Legacy Swift Language Version**" to **YES**

But still i am having errors, which stops me from compiling.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

In your podfile,

write the below line:-

```
use_frameworks!
```

Example:-

```
 use_frameworks!

    target 'YourAppName' do

    pod 'Charts'
end
```